# Is it possible for a NSTimer to trigger before the specified time?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I have been using NSTimers to trigger certain events in my app which are time-sensitive (basically that have to happen when I tell them to happen with up to the second resolution). However, I have been experiencing that, some times, the timer fires before, so that if I record the date at which the timer fires, it might say `14:34:59` instead of `14:35:00`. This is a bit annoying. I searched the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for an explanation and found this:

- Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the
  effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to
  on the order of 50-100 milliseconds.

and this:

- If a timer’s firing time occurs during a long callout or while the
  run loop is in a mode that is not monitoring the timer, the timer
  does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer.

So timers have a resolution of 100 milisecs, which could explain why the timer triggers before, but only if that made any sense. And the reason why it doesn't is that one would think the 100ms difference is caused by *delays*, not the contrary.

So, **1:** why are timers triggereing before their time, and **2:** how can I avoid this?

**EDIT:**

This is how I am calculating the date:

1. I start with a NSDate object (either [NSDate now] or a date from a NSDatePicker)
2. I add to that date *x* number of days using NSDateComponents
3. I set the the hour, number and seconds of that date (but keeping the day/month/year from step 2), again using NSDateComponents
4. I set the timer this way:

   timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 10 target: self selector: @selector(myMethod) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];

   [timer setFireDate: firingDate];

   [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: timer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];

**EDIT 2:**

I have also logged the time interval (instead of the hours/minutes/seconds) and it is always `x.0000`, which means it is at the exact start of the second, exactly how it should be (not before, not after).

Comment: 1. if you care about millisecond differences you should not log the time only in seconds. for all we know those 14:34:59 might be 14:34:59:999 ...    2. can you show how you create a timer? how do you know you set it to run at 13:35:00:000 and not at 13:35:00:999 ?

Comment: If the variance is being caused by other input sources you could start  a new thread with its own run loop and put the timer on that run loop.

Comment: @CoryPowers I don't really care about delays, as long as the timer still triggers on the same second it was told to. But do you think advances are also created by input sources?

Comment: @Alex I doubt it, its probably just run at the first opportunity within the tolerance. But if you are on a separate thread you could possibly sleep the thread the number of microseconds you need to wait to get to the right resolution in the case of an advance.

Comment: @bazik I have updated my question with more info.

Comment: If you only care that it triggers with the second, why don't you add an extra half second to the firing time?

Comment: @SteveWaddicor That is an option, of course, and I think that's what I'm going to do. It's the simplest, but if the problems persist I can always try something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you are calculating the time interval (seconds) incorrectly. Note that this is an NSTimeInterval, which is defined as a double. Are you per chance rounding the time interval to the nearest second? In that case when rounding down the timer will fire too early.

**Edit:** There is indeed empirical evidence that NSTimer may fire early. My guess is that the accuracy mentioned in the documentation is not just + but +/- and the runloop does something along to the lines of `if(fireDelta>-0.0xxx) then fireNow();`.

So to work around that:

- Always add a small delta to the firing time and hope the delta is enough (ugly and not guaranteed)
- When the timer fires, do `if(timer.fireDate.timeIntervalSinceNow>0.0) then` and reschedule a timer with the same fireDate. Still ugly...

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail. As you can see, I am not using NSTimeInterval, so the milisecond value persists through my calculations. And neither NSDateComponents nor NSDate allow setting just the miliseconds component of a date to zero.

Comment: There's also a third option suggested by Cory Powers in a comment above: create a thread with its own runloop and add the timer to that runloop. When the timer fires, if it fires too early, wait the necessary amount of milisecs to compensate. Then call my time-sensitive method. Do you think this is a good idea (less ugly than the others)?

Comment: That would work, though it seems rather more complex than just setting up a new timer with the same fire date as the timer that has fired. Your choice!

Comment: I think I'm going to try the simplest option first: add a 0.3 sec delta to the firing time and see if that works...